# How to automatically escape special characters in Sexpr in knitr?

Tags: knitr

I have the following code in a knitr doc:

```
\title{Metrics for \Sexpr{display_name}}
```

where `display_name` was set by some previous code.

If that name has special characters (e.g., `Mary & Sue Industries`), then latex barfs:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\@title ->Metrics for Mary &
                              Sue Industries
```

I've seen a couple of questions about quoting special characters ([expandafter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351863/automatically-escape-special-characters), also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter), also [perl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119383/69822)), but I don't understand how to apply them to my situation.  Is there any knitr or latex function or macro I can use?

I'm using knitr 1.26 and pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019).

Comment: Try Mary \\& Sue. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430722.

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493645

Comment: The second reference is what I want: `xtable::sanitize`.